# Inline javascript to refresh a webpage automaticaliy at given interval and check for a change in a div element

Tags: javascript, html, reload, intervals

I am trying to make an inline script (a script to put as a bookmark in the browser) that needs to refresh a webpage automatically at an interval (15 or 20 seconds) and check for a change in an element. Than if that elements meets certain criteria, to click on a button.

Imagine an ebay listing, the script checks the html element with the price and compares it to a value stored in the session storage. If the price is below a given price it clicks on a button to buy the item.

I can't put any code in the website, all I can do is execute the inline script from the bookmark.

Basically I want to click on the bookmark and from there on the page needs to start refreshing every 15 seconds until the tab is closed.

I found this code:

```js
javascript:
var current = location.href,
 timer = setTimeout('reload()', 20000);
 
 //if I put the logic here it only executes once and then does not check for a change in the div element

function reload(){ 
 
 //if I put the logic here it does not have access to the DOM and can't check for the changes. 
  
 setTimeout('reload()',20000); 
 
 fr4me='<frameset cols=\'*\'>\n<frame src=\''+current+'\'/>'; 
 fr4me+='</frameset>'; 
 
 with(document){
  write(fr4me);
  void(close())
 }; 
 
 
}
```

But as mentioned in the comments - the document.getElementById either works only once if placed at the top, or it doesn't work at all if inside the reset function.

So any suggestions? Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult as a bookmarklet because the page (and any changes) will disappear in each reload.  There are ways to work around it, but it won't be easy.

If you are using Chrome, Safari, Opera or Firefox, it would be far easier to create a UserScript that runs *outside* the page to get the affect you are after.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` will reload your page once when the document is ready.

What about using `setInterval`?

**Example:**

```
setInterval(reload, 20000);
```

Each `20s`, your page will be reloaded.